# PHP str_replace; check for more than the replace part

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

Let's say I have the following code:

```
$string = "Hello! This is a test. Hello this is a test!"

echo str_replace("Hello", "Bye", $string);
```

This will replace all `Hello` in `$string` with `Bye`. How can I e.g. exclude all where there's `!` after `Hello`.

Means, I want this output: `Hello! This is a test. Bye this is a test!`

Is there a way in php to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a regular expression:

```
echo preg_replace("/Hello([^!])/", "Bye$1", $string);
```

`[]` is a character class and the `^` means NOT.  So `Hello` NOT followed by `!`.  Capture in `()` the NOT `!` that is after `Hello` so you can use it in the replacement as `$1` (first capture group).

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `preg_repalce` function with specific regex pattern:

```
$string = "Hello! This is a test. Hello this is a test!";
$result = preg_replace("/Hello(?!\!)/", "Bye", $string);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Hello! This is a test. Bye this is a test!
```

`(?!\!)` - lookahead negative assertion, matches `Hello` word only if it's NOT followed by '!'